# Using Content Delivery to send custom PDF files

Tags: content-delivery

Currently, we send out custom PDF reports to our Partners manually (attach via email).  These PDFs are generated by an external program (no Salesforce data, only business specific stuff).

I want to find a way to send these PDFs to Partner users and keep a record of this in Salesforce.

One probable solution (I think) is to use Content Delivery on the Contact record and upload these PDFs.

Is this a good solution?

Another reason I think Content Delivery is good, is that some of our Partners have Salesforce license, while most of them do not.  Using Content Delivery, I can send these unique PDFs to individual Partners who do not have a Salesforce license.

Any other solution will be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is quite a subjective question, there really is no right or wrong answer, but I do think this is a decent solution.

Another reason to use Content and content delivery is the version control and collaboration.  This way you can have archived copies of all versions of the PDF as well as have some conversation and collaboration internally should you need to make changes to the document.

Not knowing your specific situation, another thing that could be done is to send the email with PDF attachment using Apex either in a trigger or a scheduled and/or batch job.  This would give you the advantage of being able to schedule emails and do it in bulk.